# How do I use a split indicator instead of test_train_split()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am splitting movie reviews into training and test sets, but there is a split indicator in the excel file which tells us what is test vs train. I'm not sure how to use the resulting dataframes for this way of splitting, in order to get my program to work.

This is how I am splitting the set, but what do I do with train_df and test_df now? How are they applied vs if I used `train_test_split()` and got back X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test?

```
train_df = data[data['Split'] == "train"]  # splitting data based on the split indicator
test_df = data[data['Split'] == "test"]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) returns the split data and the original indices, which is important to be able to tell what was the original position.

You can access this using the index with your method.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': list('ABCDEF'),
                   'Split': ['train', 'test', 'test', 'train', 'train', 'test']})

train_df = df[df['Split'] == "train"]
test_df  = df[df['Split'] == "test"]

y_test  = test_df.index
# [1, 2, 5]
y_train = train_df.index
# [0, 3, 4]
```

But you don't really need those as the split it not random in your case.

Comment: Perfect thanks! And the X_train would just be X_train = train_df['Review']? Considering 'Review' is the column with the raw text data, i.e. features

Comment: Or maybe `X_train = train_df.loc[df['Split'] == "train", 'Review']`?